# How NHibernate implement the batching operation?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, batching

What is the solution of NHibernate for batching operations?

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking how is it implemented internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate is open source. You can [download source codes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/) and check the whole implementation.

- For batching insert / update / delete commands start with `AbstractBatcher` class
- For batching selects start with `FutureBatch` class